# How to use click event to fill textarea with javascript input

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, click, textarea

I have a textarea in which people should be able to link to other topics on my site. I have 6 buttons which are `OnClick` now, but I want it easier to implement, so I want a `click event` instead of it...

The problem is that I don't know how to do it. For example, if someone clicks on a certain button, it has to pop-up a javascript pop-up with a input field in which people can fill a URL to a website or topic. After this is filled, it has to be automatically put down on the textarea.

How can I do this?

This is what I have tried:

```
<?php
if ($verified_user) {
  echo "
<form method=post action=\"\" class=post> 

<textarea id=\"qut\"></textarea>

<div class=wtf>
        <input type=\"button\" class=\"button\" onclick=\"hen('d','--! ($language[spoil]: spoiler) !--\n\r','\n\r--! ($language[spoil] : spoiler) !--\r')\" value=\"$language[spoiler]\"  />
</div>   
";    }

?>

</div>
</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Also, what have you tried? The pieces of your question have all been answered on SO already.

Comment: I ask questions that are not easy to solve :) Like this one.

Comment: Voted to close; not a real question. (I'm dubious of the others as well.)

Comment: Also, apparently exact duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14026044/7469

Comment: See my comment on your comment.

Comment: If you think it is duplicate, than you can't read at all.

Comment: Same code block in two downvoted questions; 0 accepted answers. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all, you need to check how to use event listeners. Google it and you will find this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Then you need to know how to update the content of a textbox. Again: Look for it on the Internet and you'll find `innerHTML`.

In the end it could look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zvnAH/1/

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");

if(button.addEventListener){ //FF, Chrome, Safari, IE > 9, ...
    button.addEventListener('click', addLink, false); 
}else if(button.attachEvent){ //IE < 9
    button.attachEvent('onclick', addLink);
}

function addLink(){
    var tmp = document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML;
    var link = prompt("Add link:");
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = tmp + link;
}​
```

Comment: The fiddle does not work. It does not fill the textarea... Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: What browser are you using? Did you read my link?

Comment: Firefox. I am reading it right now mate, thanks. InnerHTML was the word I was searching for apparently.

Comment: Just tried the Fiddle with Firefox, works perfectly for me.

Comment: I changed Mootools on the left and now it's working for me too. Thank you brother! I can make work of this now.

Answer (score 0):

on your button (one from the six), add this :

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open(URL_of_the_new_page_with_input_field,'name_popup','menubar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, width=200, height=100');" />
```

in the other page, you have the input field and a button OK.

use this :

```
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="window.opener.document.getElementById('the_textarea_id').value = document.getElementById('the_inputfield_id').value" />
```

May this help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate, but it is not what I need. I have a onclick already, I want a click event.

Comment: did you mean you want to fire event ?
something like $('#the_button_id').trigger() ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. If someone clicks on a button, it has to show a javascript pop-up with a (http://) in it so that people can enter a link. Besides, it has to have a second pop-up which will change the links (a href) name to anything the users writes. After clicking on ok, it should put it on the textarea...

Comment: Can you show me What have you tried ?

Comment: Well, see the first post. That is what I have tried my brother. But the whole function isn't doing the thing I want.